# Backbone - Parse object into models for collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am getting an object with several nested objects back from a `collection.fetch()` call.  Is there a way to parse these sub-objects and pass them into the collection as individual models?

Here is an example of the data I am getting back.  I'd like to pass this into the collection as 3 models when it is fetched from the server.

Here is a fiddle to what I am trying but I am not sure of the best way to go about this: http://jsfiddle.net/L8ov7oo5/

Data from server:

```
{
  "slides": {
    "date": "August 21, 2014",
    "Author": "Luke Skywalker",
    "slide1": {
        "content": {
            "headline": "headline 1",
            "desc": "description for slide 1",
            "image": [
                {
                    "url": "http://placekitten.com/100/100",
                    "type": "thumbnail",
                    "alt": "imageofakitten"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "slide2": {
        "content": {
            "headline": "headline2",
            "desc": "descriptionforslide2",
            "image": [
                {
                    "url": "http: //placekitten.com/125/125",
                    "type": "thumbnail",
                    "alt": "imageofakitten"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "slide3": {
        "content": {
            "headline": "headline3",
            "desc": "descriptionforslide3",
            "image": [
                {
                    "url": "http: //placekitten.com/150/150",
                    "type": "thumbnail",
                    "alt": "imageofakitten"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Example of model I'd like to pass to the collection:

```
{
  "slide1": {
    "content": {
      "headline": "headline 1",
      "desc": "description for slide 1",
      "image": [
        {
          "url": "http://placekitten.com/100/100",
          "type": "thumbnail",
          "alt": "imageofakitten"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my code, but when I log the results of the `collection.fetch()` I don't see 3 models in the collection.

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: MyModel,

  url: 'https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/parse-test/collections/parse-test-collection?apiKey=x5akja343lqkja',

  parse: function (response) {
    console.log('response', response);
    for (var prop in response[0].slides) {
        if ( response[0].slides.hasOwnProperty(prop) ) {

            // Try to add an object as a 'model' to the 'collection'
            this.add( response[0].slides[prop] );
        }
    }
    return response;
  }
});

var myCollection = new MyCollection();

myCollection.fetch().done(function () {
  // Expecting to see 3 models in this collection but I am not.
  console.log(myCollection);   
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parse call for your collection should return an array. Inside your for-in loop, add each of the objects you want to an array and return the array from parse when you're done.

```
var obj = response[0].slides,
    returnList = [];

for (var prop in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && prop !== 'date' && prop !== 'Author') {
      returnList.push(obj[prop]);
    }
}
return returnList;
```

here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L8ov7oo5/3/) to demonstrate.

EDIT: here's another [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L8ov7oo5/6/) to demonstrate using _.map() instead of a for-in loop.

```
var obj = response[0].slides;

delete obj.date;
delete obj.Author;
return _.map(obj, function (value, key) {
    return obj[key];
});
```

Comment: Thank you!  I did not realize it was an array that I should return.

Answer (score 3):

simply you can remove the properties date and Author and return the slides

```
  parse: function (response) {
      //console.log('response', response[0]['slides']);
      delete  response[0]['slides'].date;
      delete  response[0]['slides'].Author;
      var temp = [];
      $.each( response[0]['slides'], function(index, val) {
         temp.push(val);
      });
      return temp;
  }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L8ov7oo5/7/)

Comment: I like your use of delete to get rid of the unwanted properties, but you still want to return an array for a collection, not an object.